# ng2-smart-table: How to preselect dropdown with the current value in edit mode

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I have a column that need to be a dropDown upon edit.

When i press edit i get the full dropdown but no selected value

Here is my code:

```
        CompanyName: {
          title: 'CompanyName,
          type: 'html',
          valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => {
            return row.CompanyName
          },
          editor: {
            type: 'list',
            config: {
              list: this.companies  // this.companies = [{value: 1, title: "TestCompany"]
            }
          }
        },
```

Comment: If something not clear please ask and i'll provide more info

Answer (score 1):

Can you try-

```
valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => {
            return row.title
          },
```

Reference-
https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/665